# How to get JSON data from exception in httpClient()

Tags: 8

```
  public function myLogin() {
    try {
      $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
      $request = $client->post('https://targetApi.com/auth/login?fx=1', [
             'json' => [
                 'login' => 'demo',
                 'password' => 'demo1234567',
                 'locale' => 'en'
              ]
      ]);
      $response = json_decode($request->getBody());
      return $respone;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('autoapp')->error($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
```

When I set wrong password I can catch this in $e->getMessage(). The message is:

```
Client error: `POST https://targetApi.com/auth/login?fx=1` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"error":"auth.user.notfound"}
```

So I can catch error, this is fine. But I'd like to get JSON data from It. And if in the `try` part I have it in `$request->getBody()`, how can I get it from $e ?

Comment: What type is `$e`? If it's a Guzzle exception of some sort you can probably use `$e->hasResponse()` to see if there's a response, then `$e->getResponse()` to get it

Comment: I'm getting Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with get_class($s)

Comment: I'm getting $e->getResponse(), but there is no "auth.user.notfound" in it.  How can I get this response?

Comment: It’s a response object so without checking I’d assume via its `getBody()` method. Although I think there might be a `json` method as well.

Comment: I finally figured it all out. `$e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()` is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
if ($e->hasResponse()) {
    $response = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
}
```